# Cannot add legend to ggplot line-plot

Tags: ggplot2, legend, line-plot

I am a new R user and I am trying to add a legend to my lines plot. This is the command line that I used to make the plot and the relative plot.

`ggplot(crab_tag$daylog, aes(Date))+ geom_line(aes(y=-Max.Depth), color="blue")+ geom_line(aes(y=-Min.Depth),color="violet")+ labs(x="Date",y="Depth(m)")+ theme(legend.position = c(0,1),legend.justification = c(0,1)) +scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","violet"))`

Anyone can help me to see my error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this thread https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-manual-legend-to-ggplot2/41651/2 I found the following: The issue here is that you have to link the colour to the legend (and also have to call the legend). Here is a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)`
library(learningr)`

ggplot(crab_tag$daylog, aes(Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=-Max.Depth, colour = "Max.Depth")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=-Min.Depth, colour = "Min.Depth"))+ 
  labs(x="Date",y="Depth(m)", colour = "legend")+ 
  theme(legend.position = c(0,1),legend.justification = c(0,1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Max.Depth"="blue","Min.Depth"="violet"))
```

You see, the main changes is to call colour within the `aes()` function and there define the variable name you want to use in the legend, the label of the colour legend in labs, and the named vector for values in `scale_colour_manual()`

Comment: Thank you Owe for your suggestions and advice. I managed to add the legend and to understand what I was doing wrong. I appreciate it!